# Microsoft Access Update Query - Insert Primary Key from Another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Allrighty, been stuck for few days since I'm completely new to MS Access.

Let's say I have three tables:

- OrderTable (containing fields: otID as auto-numbered primary key, custID, Ref).
- CustomerTable (containing fields: custID as auto-numbered primary key, custName, custPhone and custEmail).
- OP-tMain (containing fields: custName, custPhone, custEmail and Ref).

All the data is stored in Excel and I'll be using OperationTable to process and store data in Access.

I could do UPDATE QUERY to update the CustomerTable just fine. After updating CustomerTable, I need to update the order table. The issue that I'm facing is that in the OrderTable, I left out the custName, custPhone and custEmail and just use custID (which I believe the right way to do). Anyone can help me on how to UPDATE/INSERT the data from OP-tMain and pull the corresponding cID from the CustomerTable?

EDIT. Sample file uploaded here ==> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fK3IDEd54Jfr6c-U2s5Bnm4TeK2TQZnM/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a joined query for append and update:

**Append Query**

```
INSERT INTO OrderTable (CustId, Ref)
SELECT c.CustID, o.Ref
FROM CustomerTable c
INNER JOIN [OP-tMain] o
ON c.custName = o.custName
```

**Update Query** to update *Ref* column with a correlated count match for multiple *Ref* entries per customer

```
UPDATE (OrderTable m
INNER JOIN CustomerTable c ON c.CustID = m.CustID)
INNER JOIN [OP-tMain] o ON c.custName = o.custName
SET m.Ref = o.Ref
WHERE DCOUNT("*", "OrderTable", "otID <=" & m.otID & " AND custID =" & m.custID) = 
      DCOUNT("*", "[OP-tMain]", "ID <=" & o.ID & " AND custName ='" & o.custName & "'")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works 99%. The only issue is that the Update Query seems to messed up the REF. Here is the op-tMain table which should be copied to OrderTable: https://imgur.com/a/6cKhe and here is the OrderTable : https://imgur.com/a/mwKBW

Comment: What's wrong with the images? From what I see *Ref* values correspond to same *CustID*.

Comment: customer ID 1 got 2 entries with 1st Ref = random and 2nd Ref = goes. Need to keep both ref.

Comment: Try edited answer matching the rows by correlated counts for multiple *Ref* per customer.

Comment: Thank you but i got syntax error on DCOUNT("*", "OrderTable", "otID <=" m.otID & " AND custName ='" & m.custName & "'") = 
      DCOUNT("*", "[OP-tMain]", "ID <=" o.ID & " AND custName ='" & o.custName & "'");

Comment: Should I make otID also present at OP-tMain (made that as PK) + change it from auto-number to short text? Currently, OP-tMain primary key is using auto-number.

Comment: Whooops! I missed some ampersands, `&`. What happens when typing on a tablet. Try again.

Comment: Looks like it should work, just need to solve m.CustName as there's no CustName on m. WHERE DCOUNT("*", "OrderTable", "otID <=" & m.otID & " AND custName ='" & m.custName & "'").

Comment: Simply replace with *custID*.